# How to get modal class data by using position in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can i get the data from DataModal.java class using item position i have only item position that i received from fragment now i want to get data from DataModal.java class using this position i implements some codes but it's given errors below my codes

**My DataModal.java class**

```
List<DataModal> productList;

 public void OnItemClickActivity(int position) {
    final DataModal product = productList.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Posiotion product" + product,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

These are my codes but application crashing not open so please help me anyone here.

Comment: what type of error do you get?

Comment: productList return null

Comment: there is no data in the product list so they return a null value.

Comment: how can i initialize productList then the productList returning me data?

Comment: please include proper code

Answer (score 1):

first you have to initialize your list :

```
List<DataModal> productList; = new ArrayList<DataModal>();
```

then add some item to that list :

```
productList.add(new DataModal(constructor parameter));
```

and then you can get item by calling:

```
final DataModal product = productList.get(position);
```